# sed regex the last match

Tags: regex, linux, sed

I want to change in file in each line the last match to the XXXX
Given the file format:

```
"192.xx2" "someting" "another2321SD"
```

I want to have:

```
"192.xx2" "someting" "XXXX"
```

only using sed
My solution:

```
sed -r 's/"(?:.(?!".+"))+$/XXXX/' file
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please bear in mind that

- `(?:...)` is a [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-in-regular-expressions) and [POSIX regex](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html) does not support this construct
- `(?!...)` is a negative [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and POSIX regex does not support this construct either.

*To mask all content in between the last pair of double quotation marks*, you can use

```sh
sed -r 's/(.*)".*"/\1"XXXX"/' file
sed 's/\(.*\)".*"/\1"XXXX"/' file
```

See the [`sed` demo](https://ideone.com/b9ocoB):

```sh
s='"192.xx2" "someting" "another2321SD"'
sed -r 's/(.*)".*"/\1"XXXX"/' <<< "$s"
# => "192.xx2" "someting" "XXXX"
```

Comment: At https://stackoverflow.com/a/66778854/3220113 you ask for an improvement. I don't know, if my answers are better but you could also assume that the `"` is the last character of the input: `sed 's/"[^"]*"$/"XXXX"/' <<< "$s"`. When you are not sure (or when you are charged for every double quote you use), you can use `rev < <(sed -r 's/[^"]+/XXXX/' <( rev <<<"$s"))`. Worse seems to be `awk -F '"' 'BEGIN { OFS="\""} { $(NF-1)="XXXX"; print  }' <<< "$s"`.

Comment: @WalterA Thanks, Walter. Assuming the last quoted part is really close to the end of string, I think the current approach should be already good enough. I did not consider `awk` due to question tags, I think there can be many more assumptions then.

Answer (score 1):

Remember what was there before the last pair of double quotes in a capture.

```
sed -r 's/^(.*)"[^"]*"$/\1"XXXX"/'
```