# sed change string delimiting with ocurrences

Tags: sed

I am trying to change the next line using 'sed' command

```
"metamodes" "DFP-0: 2048x2048 +1920+0, DFP-2: 1280x1024 +640+0, DFP-1: 1920x1080 +0+1024"
```

I need sed command find the resolution 2048x2048 or 1280x1024 or 1920x1080 and change the position (+1920+0 or +640+0 or +0+1024). Like this position is not always the same, I cannot sed only this position and I have to find the resolution (that always will be the same) and change the link position to the resolution.

The final result should be:

```
"metamodes" "DFP-0: 2048x2048 +1280+0, DFP-2: 1280x1024 +0+1024, DFP-3: 1920x1080 +1408+4440"
```

I used the next command:

```
sed 's/2048x2048.*[^,]/2048x2048 +1280+0,/g' /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

Any suggestion?
thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO, thanks for sharing your attempts in form of code. Your code/samples were not covered in code tags, I had tried to fix them but not sure if your actual files looking like this only? So please do edit your samples to make it clear for us(in case this edited samples are not looking same as your actual ones), thank you.

Answer (score 1):

With `.*[^,]` you match "any character as much as possible when the last character is not a `,`. You want to match everything until the first `,`. Use `[^,]*`:
sed 's/2048x2048[^,]*/2048x2048 +1280+0/g' /etc/X11/xorg.conf

The 3 replacements can be combined:

```
sed 's/2048x2048[^,]*/2048x2048 +1280+0/g;
     s/1280x1024[^,]*/1280x1024 +640+0/g;
     s/1920x1080[^,]*/1920x1080 +0+1024/g' /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

Testing this will show, that the `"` is matched too, so you need to add the quote to the character class:

```
sed 's/2048x2048[^,"]*/2048x2048 +1280+0/g;
     s/1280x1024[^,"]*/1280x1024 +640+0/g;
     s/1920x1080[^,"]*/1920x1080 +0+1024/g' /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```